# git log in JSON - send changelog to browser

Tags: json, node.js, git, node-streams

In order to know what's actually been committed to a project in production, we are going to display the Git log to admins - this serve as a makeshift changelog.

I have this routine on a Node.js Express server:

```
 router.get('/changelog/json', ac.allow('ROLE_ADMIN'), function (req, res, next) {

  const k = cp.spawn('bash');

  k.stdin.write('git log --pretty=format:\'{%n  "commit": "%H",%n  "abbreviated_commit": "%h",%n  "tree": "%T",%n  "abbreviated_tree": "%t",%n  "parent": "%P",%n  "abbreviated_parent": "%p",%n  "refs": "%D",%n  "encoding": "%e",%n  "subject": "%s",%n  "sanitized_subject_line": "%f",%n  "body": "%b",%n  "commit_notes": "%N",%n  "verification_flag": "%G?",%n  "signer": "%GS",%n  "signer_key": "%GK",%n  "author": {%n    "name": "%aN",%n    "email": "%aE",%n    "date": "%aD"%n  },%n  "commiter": {%n    "name": "%cN",%n    "email": "%cE",%n    "date": "%cD"%n  }%n},\'\n')

  k.stdin.end();
  k.stdout.pipe(res);


});
```

this sort of works, but we don't actually get a JSON array, we just get comma separate JSON strings.

I got this info form here:
https://gist.github.com/varemenos/e95c2e098e657c7688fd
https://git-scm.com/docs/pretty-formats

**does anyone know how I can construct a JSON array from the stdout from the Git command?**

I tried this:

```
router.get('/json', ac.allow('ROLE_ADMIN'), function (req, res, next) {

  const p = createParser();

  const k = cp.spawn('bash', [], {
    cwd: global.cdtProjectRoot
  });

  const items = [];

  k.stdin.write('git log --pretty=format:\'{%n  "commit": "%H",%n  "abbreviated_commit": "%h",%n  "tree": "%T",%n  "abbreviated_tree": "%t",%n  "parent": "%P",%n  "abbreviated_parent": "%p",%n  "refs": "%D",%n  "encoding": "%e",%n  "subject": "%s",%n  "sanitized_subject_line": "%f",%n  "body": "%b",%n  "commit_notes": "%N",%n  "verification_flag": "%G?",%n  "signer": "%GS",%n  "signer_key": "%GK",%n  "author": {%n    "name": "%aN",%n    "email": "%aE",%n    "date": "%aD"%n  },%n  "commiter": {%n    "name": "%cN",%n    "email": "%cE",%n    "date": "%cD"%n  }%n},\'\n')
  k.stdin.end();

  k.stdout.pipe(p).on('data', function (d) {
     // d would be a parsed JSON object
    items.push(d);
  })
  .once('error', next)
  .once('end', function () {

    res.json({
      success: items
    })
  })

});
```

My parser transform works, because I use it in another project, so it's something about the format of the JSON coming from the stdout that's causing the problem - the 'data' event handler never sees any data.

Comment: Many of the fields you're extracting from the log via your format string *could* contain characters that are "special" to JSON. Suppose, for example, that the commit subject contains a double-quote character; now what will happen?  It would be much better to build the object you're trying to represent in Javascript and then stringify it, rather than try to extract the stringified representation from a tool that was never intended to generate JSON.

Comment: yeah that makes sense - so maybe get the fields I want and split by white space? I guess I just need to know what order each of the fields has, and then I can put that into an object. If you show a simple example I will upvote.

Comment: yeah I realized that parsing the output manually was hard - so I stuck with JSON, just simplified the --pretty=format a bit.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me, I had to improve the git log format option:

```
router.get('/json', ac.allow('ROLE_ADMIN'), function (req, res, next) {

  const p = createParser();
  const k = cp.spawn('bash');

  let items = [];

  k.stdin.write(`git log -300 --pretty=format:'{"commit":"%H","sanitized_subject_line":"%f","commit_notes":"%N","author":"%aN","date":"%aD"}'`);
  k.stdin.end('\n');

  k.stdout.pipe(p).on('data', function (d) {
    items.push(JSON.parse(d));
  })
  .once('error', next)
  .once('end', function () {

    res.json({
      success: items
    })
  })

});
```

createParser looks like this:

```
const stream = require("stream");

exports.createParser = function () {

  let lastLineData = '';

  let strm = new stream.Transform({

    objectMode: true,

    transform: function (chunk, encoding, cb) {
      let _this = this;
      let data = String(chunk);
      if (lastLineData) {
        data = lastLineData + data;
      }
      let lines = data.split('\n');
      lastLineData = lines.splice(lines.length - 1, 1)[0];
      lines.forEach(function (l) {
        l && _this.push(l);
      });
      cb();
    },

    flush: function (cb) {
      if (lastLineData) {
        this.push(lastLineData);
      }
      lastLineData = '';
      cb();
    }
  });

  return strm;
};
```

this might barf if there are certain characters in the git log fields, like Author, but I think the built-in field "sanitized_subject_line" will save our skin a bit when it comes to removing bad chars from commit messages.